# Storing array of ids as different entity in Laravel -Mysql

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have A Table

```
    id Primary  bigint(20)UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    school_id   bigint(20)UNSIGNED   Foreign Key,
    teacher_id  bigint(20)UNSIGNED   Foreign Key,
    course_id   bigint(20)UNSIGNED   Foreign Key,
    klass_id    bigint(20)UNSIGNED   Foreign Key,
```

I Want to add Some data To this table, My data is given below.

```
 {
    "school_id":5,
    "teacher_id":2,
    "course_id":[1,2,3],
    "klass_id":[7,8,3],
 }
```

How Can I store this data Like Below

```
--id|school_id|teacher_id|course_id|klass_id
----------------------------------------------
  1 |    5    |     2    |     1   |    7
  2 |    5    |     2    |     2   |    8
  3 |    5    |     2    |     3   |    3
```

Comment: Welcome to SO... did you tried anything to solve this?

Comment: @KamleshPaul No.. How Can I solve this?

Comment: using loop which have big count loop at that count and insert

Comment: @KamleshPaul Okay But the course_id is related to klass_id .. How can I insert it as correct match like course_id 1 with klass_id 7

Comment: inside loop you can match no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input is always gonna be in the format of

```
"school_id" will have 1 value,
"teacher_id" will have 1 value,
"course_id" will have x values,
"klass_id" will have x values,
```

Then you can do something like:

```
$mapped = [];
for($i=0; $i<count($data['course_id']); $i++) {
    $mapped[] = [
        "school_id" => $data['school_id'],
        "teacher_id" => $data['teacher_id'],
        "course_id" => $data['course_id'][$i],
        "klass_id" => $data['klass_id'][$i]
    ]
}
```

Then you can call any eloquent or DB function to insert like:

```
Model::insertMany($mapped);
```

P.S: There must be a better way of doing it that I don't know of. :(

Comment: Sometimes Course_id and klass_id may have only one value..

Comment: If the values will be in `array`, this implementation will still work.

Comment: What if we have morethan one klass_ids and only single course_id??

Comment: I already described the format in the question for it to work. If `klass_id` and `course_id` have different number of values, this will fail.

Comment: There must be a collection way to do that too that I'm unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to save this data manually? if yes, create database SEED and add these data in array format like below: create a class with command `php artisan make:seeder CreateSeedTableName` and add this below code

```
$arr = [
[
 "school_id" => 5,
 "teacher_id" => 2,
 "course_id" => 1,
 "klass_id" => 7
],
[
 "school_id" => 5,
 "teacher_id" => 2,
 "course_id" => 2,
 "klass_id" => 8
],
[
 "school_id" => 5,
 "teacher_id" => 2,
 "course_id" => 3,
 "klass_id" => 3
]
];
TableName::insert($arr);
```

or you can use loop if you have same format data in request.

```
$count = count($data['course_id']); //get course count
$schoolId = $data['school_id']; //get school id
$teacherId = $data['teacher_id']; //get teacher id
 for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) { 
  TableName::create([
   'school_id' => $schoolId,
   "teacher_id" => $teacherId,
    "course_id" => $data['course_id'][$i],
    "klass_id" => $data['klass_id'][$i],
]);
}
```

Comment: What if we have only one course and morethan one klass_ids.. like one course can be in morethan one class

Comment: then you have to make `if else` condition on the count of both `klass_id and course_id`.